# NPE While getting Device ID for android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm getting an NPE while trying to use device ID as string.
Here is my main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {
public String device_ID(){
    final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return tm.getDeviceId();
   }
}
```

The code I'm trying to call ID with:

```
String device_id = new Main().device_ID();
```

Comment: post the logcat

Comment: Use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `getBaseContext()` and what is the `KikApplication` ?

Comment: @Piyush I updated my question, forgot to rename my class when posting for help

Comment: Do you add permission in menifest file?

Comment: yes I did add permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this method instead

```
public class Main extends Application {
public String device_ID(){
    final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return tm.getDeviceId();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this;

Main

```
public class Main extends Application {
   public static String device_ID(Activity context){
      final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      return tm.getDeviceId();
    }
 }
```

Now call this method anywhere in project like this:

```
String device_id = Main.device_ID(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Pretty sure, You cannot use getBaseContext() with static methods

Comment: Then use getApplicationContext();

Comment: I do not have an activity class :/

Comment: Then where do you want to call device_Id() function?

Comment: Another class that extends ```AsyncTask``` and getApplicationContext() does not work on static

Comment: There is no need to call AsyncTask...just call String device_id = Main.device_ID(MainActivity.this); and u will get device id and then pass it any where in your class

Comment: Dont use getApplicationContext();

Comment: Use your_class_name.this

Comment: My class is not an activity, my class needs to be AsyncTask I'm doing heavy background task.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static instance of your Application, and then use in your app anywhere.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private static Main mInstance;

    public static String device_ID(){
       final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) mInstance.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       return tm.getDeviceId();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }
}
```

And you can call like this from anywhere from you app,

```
Main.device_ID();
```